# Can't import json data from Google Storage Cloud into Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, anaconda, google-cloud-storage

I've an issue with reading data from a json file residing in a google storage bucket into a dataframe-

```
%env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = /my_path/artcollect/google-api-keys.json
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('my_bucket')
blob = bucket.get_blob('my_data.json')
content = blob.download_as_string()
```

When running

```
lots = pd.read_json(content)
```

I'm getting a `ValueError: Trailing data`. `content` returns

```
b'[\n{\n    "auction_house_name": "Phillips",\n    "url": "https://www.phillips.com/detail/ARTURO-HERRERA/NY000312/1",\n    "sale_id": "NY000312", .....
```

I tried following:

```
c = re.sub(' +',' ',content.decode('utf-8').replace('\n', ""))
```

to remove the newlines and multiple spaces. `c` returns

```
'[{ "auction_house_name": "Phillips", "url": "https://www.phillips.com/detail/ARTURO-HERRERA/NY000312/1", "sale_id": "NY000312", .....
```

`pd.read_json(c)` still returns the `ValueError: Trailing data`. The full error log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-e9efacd0aab2> in <module>()
----> 1 lots = pd.read_json(c)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines)
    352         obj = FrameParser(json, orient, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates,
    353                           keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float,
--> 354                           date_unit).parse()
    355 
    356     if typ == 'series' or obj is None:

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in parse(self)
    420 
    421         else:
--> 422             self._parse_no_numpy()
    423 
    424         if self.obj is None:

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
    637         if orient == "columns":
    638             self.obj = DataFrame(
--> 639                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
    640         elif orient == "split":
    641             decoded = dict((str(k), v)

ValueError: Trailing data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might try doing a json.loads on your data and look at the dictionary result -- you may see something in the conversion that way. You could pass the dict into pandas as well. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.loads

Comment: What does the end of your JSON look like? Maybe there's an extra character or two after the closing square brace?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough no extra chars            `....."checksum": "ae6c6536afa7db95b1c8a956733eafeb"
        }
    ]
}`
]

Comment: it seems I found the issue. Searched for a ][ and found an occurrence. Obviously I appended new data to the old data

Comment: this was the issue. I scraped more than once without deleting the scrapy output file and the new data got appended to previously scraped data

Comment: Would you mind posting an answer explaining what happened? It might end up helping somebody in the future if they make a similar mistake.

Comment: Will do. Give me 2-3 days because I have a very slow internet connection at the moment

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not really related to Google Storage or misused Pandas functionality. The problem was that my json file was not correctly formatted. The reason was that the process which created the json data required that there was an empty or no file. In my test scenario I started the process a couple of times, so at the end my data file had a couple of lists appended to each other such as

```
[....... json content 1
]
[....... json content 2
]
```

I found this out by searching for `][`.

The way how I access a json file residing in a Google bucket within Jupyter was correct:

```
%env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = /my_path/google-api-keys.json
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('my_bucket')
blob = bucket.get_blob('my_data.json')
content = blob.download_as_string()
my_df = pd.read_json(content)
```

The Google API keys file can be created from the console via `APIs & Services > Credentials > Create credentials > Service Account key > select JSON`